# Peewee, вставка данных

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, insert, peewee

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у меня есть две таблицы, одна ссылается на другую.

```
class TEST(Model):
    Sub = ForeignKeyField(
        SUBSCRIPTION,
        db_column='ID',
        related_name='tests',
        primary_key=False,
    )
    Title = FixedCharField(45)
    ID = AutoField
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

и вторая таблица

```
class SUBSCRIPTION(IElement):
    WorkoutsCount = IntegerField(default=30)
    CompletedWorkouts = IntegerField(default=0)
```

ну и интерфейс

```
class IElement(BaseModel):
    ID = AutoField()
```

При попытке вставить строку в таблицу TEST peewee пытается вставить значения не туда куда надо:

```
i = TEST.insert(Title = 'ТЕЕЕСТ', Sub = 5).sql()
print(i)
```

выводит следующее:

> ('INSERT INTO "test" ("ID", "Title") VALUES (?, ?)', [5, 'ТЕЕЕСТ'])

Я без понятия как указать Peewee на то что ID должен сам автоинкриментиться, а Sub я указываю и он должен записаться соответственно в Sub, а не в ID.
Прошу помощи, сам пытался исправить это, но безрезультатно.

Comment: У вас в модели TEST прямым текстом прописано, что Sub это и есть ID. Вот он и записывает Sub в ID как положено. Так что вопрос непонятен прям совсем

Comment: И вообще для одной и той же колонки ID вы создали целых два поля в модели TEST — ID и Sub. Это очень странно

Comment: db_column - это вроде название столбца из другой таблицы, на которую как раз идет ссылка

Comment: Нет, это название столбца для поля Sub в таблице TEST. Какой столбец использовать для связи, Peewee выбирает автоматически

Comment: Если точнее, можно указать столбец и вручную, но в Peewee 2.10 это делается через `to_field` (в Peewee 3 просто `field`), а не через `db_column`

Comment: Да, действительно так, извиняюсь за свою тупость. Большое спасибо за помощь.